# data entered in python is not being reflected back in sql database

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-connector

"""hey i was making an extremely basic online store program for my seniors in class 12th.
In this i created a table users_pass to store emails and their passwords of pre-existing users of the store. When user opted for signup i wrote code to store emails and passwords enterd by new user on signup so s/he may later login next time when he visits """

code snippped that intended to do s0--->>>.
def account():

```
global Login
Login = False
print("""  Enter:
    1    -  Login
    2    -  Signup\n""")
acc = int(input())

if acc == 1:
    print("PASSWORD is CaSe SeNsAtIvE so enter carefully!!!")
    print("              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ")
    email = input("  Email address       ")
    password = input("  Password           ")
    st1 = "select * from users_pass"
    e_p = (email,password)
    cur.execute(st1)
    data = cur.fetchall()
```

#checking whether entered email and passwords are in record or not----

```
    for i in data:
        if e_p == i:
            print("  Logged in successfully")
            Login = True
            break
        else:
            if e_p[0] != i[0]:
                print("  email is incorrect")
                break
            elif e_p[1] != i[1]:
                 print("  password is incorrect")
                 break
elif acc == 2:
    print("  PASSWORD is CaSe SeNsAtIvE so enter carefully!!!")
    print("              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ")
    email = input("  Enter Your email address           ")
    password = input("  Enter Your Password               ")
    st3="insert into users_pass values('{}','{}')".format(email,password)
    cur.execute(st3)
    cur.execute("select * from users_pass")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    t = (email,password)
    print(data)
    for i in data:
        if i==t:
            print("  Account created successfully")
            Login = True
            break
```

Comment: You don't check email and passwords in a loop. You use a where clause to find that exact email. If no row returned then login fails. If one row returned then compare password. More than one means you have many people with same email which is an error in design.

Comment: Hi, Is the table **users_pass** contains an **ID** ? Can you show here the schema of the table?